# How to get the indices of top N values of an array?

Tags: c

I have a big size array that contains numbers, is there way to find the indices of top n values? Any lib function in C?

example:

an array : {1,2,6,5,3}

the indices of top 2 number is: {2,3}

Comment: So what's your effort regarding this?

Comment: If you have a concrete problem, it's also important to mention whether the original array is allowed to be modified, and whether typically `n` is much smaller than `N` or not.

Answer (score 5):

If by `top n` you mean the `n`-th highest (or lowest) number in the array, you may want to look at the [QuickSelect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm. Unfortunately there is no C library function I am aware of that implements it but Wikipedia should give you a good starting point.

QuickSelect is O(n) on average, if O(nlogn) and some overhead is fine as well, you can do `qsort` and take the `n`'th element.

**Edit** (In response to example) Getting all the indexes of the top-n in a single batch is straightforward with both approaches. QuickSelect sorts them all on one side of the final pivot.

Comment: than you Alexander, I did use qsort to do the sorting,  but i still need the original index.

Comment: Try pairing the value with the original index and then sort based on the value.

Comment: it is good idea, pair the value and index in C struct and then get top N by value?

Comment: It has x2 memory overhead, of course, but is fine unless your array is *really* large. But then again you should look at QuickSelect or its fancy friend, Median of Medians.

Answer (score 2):

So you want the top n numbers in a big array of N numbers. There is a straightforward algorithm which is O(N*n). If n is small (as it seems to be in your case) this is good enough.

```
size_t top_elems(int *arr, size_t N, size_t *top, size_t n) {
  /*
     insert into top[0],...,top[n-1] the indices of n largest elements 
     of arr[0],...,arr[N-1]
  */
  size_t top_count = 0;
  size_t i;
  for (i=0;i<N;++i) {
    // invariant: arr[top[0]] >= arr[top[1]] >= .... >= arr[top[top_count-1]]
    // are the indices of the top_count larger values in arr[0],...,arr[i-1]
    // top_count = max(i,n);
    size_t k;
    for (k=top_count;k>0 && arr[i]>arr[top[k-1]];k--);
    // i should be inserted in position k
    if (k>=n) continue; // element arr[i] is not in the top n
    // shift elements from k to top_count
    size_t j=top_count;
    if (j>n-1) { // top array is already full
      j=n-1;
    } else { // increase top array
      top_count++;
    }
    for (;j>k;j--) {
      top[j]=top[j-1];
    }
    // insert i
    top[k] = i;
  }
  return top_count;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your code, I also want the index of the top n value.

Comment: the array top contains the indexes

Comment: I think given that OP has now clarified that he wants all the top n indexes this is probably the most straightforward approach assuming `n` can be bounded.