# How to get indices of top N values of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, indices

I got the c-code from following link

[How to get the indices of top N values of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459043/how-to-get-the-indices-of-top-n-values-of-an-array)

I have added input stimulus part to the above link code and developed the following c-model

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
  double *arr =malloc(sizeof(double)*10);
  int N=10;
  int n =5;
  int *top =malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
  arr[0] = 0.00623; 
  arr[1] = 0.745;
  arr[2] = 0.440;
  arr[3] = 0.145;
  arr[4] = 0.645;
  arr[5] = 0.741;
  arr[6] = 0.542;
  arr[7] = 0.445;
  arr[8] = 0.146;
  arr[9] = 0.095;
  top[0] = 100;
  top[1] = 100;
  top[2] = 100;
  top[3] = 100;
  top[4] = 100;
  int top_count = 0;
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<N;++i) {

    // invariant: arr[top[0]] >= arr[top[1]] >= .... >= arr[top[top_count-1]]
    // are the indices of the top_count larger values in arr[0],...,arr[i-1]
    // top_count = max(i,n);
    int k;

    for (k=top_count;k>0 && arr[i]>arr[top[k-1]];k--){

    }
    // i should be inserted in position k

    if (k>=n) continue; // element arr[i] is not in the top n
    // shift elements from k to top_count
    int j=top_count;
    if (j>n-1) { // top array is already full
      j=n-1;

    } else { // increase top array
      top_count++;
    }

    for (;j>k;j--) {
      top[j]=top[j-1];
    }
    // insert i
    top[k] = i;
    printf("top[%0d] = %0d\n",k,top[k]);


  }
  return top_count;
}
```

After executing the code, I am getting following output

```
top[0] = 0
top[0] = 1
top[1] = 2
top[2] = 3
top[1] = 4
top[1] = 5
top[3] = 6
top[4] = 7
```

The index is wrong for `top[2]`. It should be `top[2] =4`. I am not able to decode why it is giving problem for only `top[2]`?

Comment: I'd suggest you to think about how you would achieve what you want to achieve and based on that to check, whether program is doing what you want. Copying some code you do not understand won't help you to learn...

Comment: In addition to Betlista's comment, it would be beneficial to you to learn to use a debugger and examine the contents of the variables as they change in your program.

Comment: As a side note, if you're going to initialize the array from code anyway, you might as well make it a normal array rather than a heap allocation (i.e. `const double arr[] = { 0.00623, 0.745, ... };`).

Comment: Why do yo need an index array of size 10 if you only want to get 5 values?

Comment: The return value of main is an indication for the OS about the program's status, 0 indicates fine, any other value indicates some error having occured...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a matter of output...

You output your latestly inserted values right while yet sorting. You get output `top[2] = 2` somewhere in your process, but later on, you shift the 2 out of the array by inserting new values *before*:

```
for (;j > k; j--)
{
    top[j] = top[j-1]; // moves the 2 out with further iterations!
}
```

What you have to do is output the sorted array *afterwards*:

```
} // for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)

// sorting finished now, so NOW output:

for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    printf("top[%0d] = %0d (%f)\n", i, top[i], arr[top[i]]);
}
```

And you'll see that your sorting actually worked as a charm...